# Название города Симбирска

Tags: топонимика

Во-первых, интересно, собираются ли Ульяновск переименовывать обратно в Симбирск, а во-вторых и в главных, интересует его название. Оно связано со словом "Сибирь" или просто созвучно?
Заранее благодарю за ответы

Answer (score 1):

Насчет переименовать - это не к нам. )))

А название с "Сибирь" никак не связано, ну если только через какую-то третью-четвертую степень этимологического родства, поскольку и там и там могут присутствовать алтайские или тюркские корни. Но установить даже эту косвенную связь невозможно, поскольку оба топонима не до конца ясны.

Сибирь связывают с тюкоязычными или монгольскими народами, на её территории проживавшими (конкретных версий много - см. источники в интернете), а о происхождении Симбирска просто копирую часть статьи из Википедии.

http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A1%D0%B8%D0%BC%D0%B1%D0%B8%D1%80%D1%81%D0%BA

О происхождении топонима Симбир высказывалось много предположений. Так, были попытки связать его с чувашским син бирен — «белая гора», с мордовским сююн бир — «зелёная гора», с тюркским сын бер — «одинокая гробница».

Но уже во второй половине прошлого века подобные объяснения были отвергнуты, как несостоятельные, не подтверждённые материалом указанных языков.

Тогда же получила распространение мысль о том, что городище Симбир обязано своим названием личному имени одного из булгарских ханов. Однако в дошедших до нас довольно обширных перечнях личных монгольских и тюркских имён XIII—XIV веков имя Симбир тоже не обнаружено. Не встречается оно и среди упоминающихся в исторических работах личных имён булгарского периода в истории Среднего Поволжья (VIII—XIII века).

Вместе с тем материалы монгольской топонимики и монгольских языков дают основание усматривать в названии Симбир монгольскую основу. В Монголии: Симбир — город в Восточно-Гобийском аймаке (области); Симбир — селение на юго-востоке Центрального аймака; Симбир — гора и т. д. И в монгольском, и в близкородственном ему бурят-монгольском языках нарицательное слово «сюмбюр» (> симбир) и сейчас употребляется в значении «священная гора». Известно, что монголы с древнейших времён на многих возвышенных местах ставили кумирни, храмы, которые по-монгольски назывались словом «сюм» (>сим). Некоторые из гор с такими кумирнями именуются словом сюмбур (> симбир). Не исключено, что в золотоордынскую эпоху, в XIII—XIV веках, такой сюм (сим) мог быть и на высоком волжском берегу. По нему, как можно полагать, были поименованы горы, а по ним — возникшие позднее селения. С момента возникновения и до конца XVIII века город официально именовали Синбирск, что было связано с особенностями произношения слова местным русско-татарским населением (замена звукосочетания мб звукосочетанием нб). В 1780 году был восстановлен более древний фонетический вариант топонима.[4]

Answer (score 0):

Это древнечувашское название, происходящее от слова "савиры" ("савир" - гора).

Comment: Очень интересно! А у вас есть ссылка на источник?